# Dynamically set instance attribute in Python

Tags: python, attributes, instance

I have a class with two instance attributes. For example:

```
class Test(): 
    def __init__(self, parameter):
        self.one = self.somefunction(parameter)
        self.two = 'somestring'
```

In the same class I define a function somefunction which will, accordingly to the above coding, be called at the time the object is created. While I tried this, I could set self.one when I return some value inside my somefunction(parameter), like:

```
def somefunction(parameter):
    return ...
```

However, this doesn't feel like best practice.What's the best way to set an initial value of an instance dynamically?

Comment: Is there a reason not to put the code inline in your init method? (Also, I assume you mean `__init__` rather than `init`, ie a constructor for the `Test` class.)

Comment: There is no reason to put it not in __init__ (I corrected my post). I thought about modularizing the code and calling methods instead of hardcoding it into the __init__ method.

Comment: It doesn't improve the code to have some initialisation code as separate methods, because separate methods should have a reason for being called separately. @Batman's answer below discusses how to separate the code out for performance reasons without resulting in a separate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with what you've done, unless `somefunction` takes a long time to return. As a rule, you don't normally want object creation/instantiation to take a long time. If it takes a long time to calculate that attribute you should do it the first time the attribute is accessed. And that can be done with property getters.

```
import time

class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, parameter):
        self._one = None
        self.two = "some_string"
        self._parameter = parameter

    @property
    def one(self):
        if self._one is None:
            self.one = self._some_method()
        return self.one

    def some_method(self):
         time.sleep(10)
         return sorted(self._parameter)
```

When you call `foo.one` Python will check to see if "protected" attribute is still `None`. If it is, *then* it will do the expensive function call. The next time you try to access it, it will use the saved value.